# how to enter command in J-link prompt using AutoIt

Tags: autoit

All,

When JlinkSTR91x.exe is invoked, it opens up a command prompt J-Link. In this prompt, we can type the commands. I need to do the same using AutoIt scripting. 
This is what I tried,

```
;Execution.au3


Local $foo = Run("C:\\Program Files\\SEGGER\\JLinkARM_V426b\\JLinkSTR91x.exe", "", @SW_SHOW, $STDIN_CHILD)

StdinWrite($foo,"setb 0")

ProcessWaitClose($foo)
```

When I run this script, J-Link prompt opens up but unable to send the command "setb 0" at this prompt. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Run("cmd")

$prog = WinWaitActive("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")

ControlSend($prog, Default, $prog, "exit")
Sleep(999)
ControlSend($prog, Default, $prog, "{Enter}")

WinWaitClose($prog)
```

This does theoretically what you want. Just replace the **cmd** with your command and insert the actual title of the prompt.You can find it out with the Info-Tool included with AutoIt.
It's just a working example.

And it will even send the text when your prompt isn't active any more. You can even hide your prompt with **WinSetState($prog, Default, @SW_HIDE)** .